# How to resolve segmentation fault (core dumped) while running in python with an matlab function call

Tags: python, matlab

```css
import matlab.engine
eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()
ret = eng.triarea(1.0,5.0)
print(ret)
```

```css
function a = triarea(b,h)
a = 0.5*(b.* h);
```

when I run this code I faced above problem 
can you please tell me what is this error and how to rectify it

Comment: I don't know anything about `matlab.engine` but I bet those who do would like to know exactly at what point you get the segfault. Which line of your Python code triggers it? "Segmentation fault" generally means that something has tried to read or write a memory location that doesn't actually exist; it usually indicates a bug in low-level code -- e.g., inside MATLAB or Python themselves (unlikely) -- or misuse of some low-level feature like calling functions from a DLL.

Comment: Is your `triarea` function in a `.m` file somewhere in your MATLAB path, or what? What happens if instead of calling `triarea` from Python you call some built-in MATLAB function?

Comment: yes, I saved in MATLAB path. and the file stops when it starts at statement    eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()

Comment: It might be worth taking a look at these, which look like a problem similar to yours: http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/180518-why-does-matlab-engine-for-python-crash-when-using-a-non-system-default-version-of-python-on-mac and http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/157278-matlab-engine-for-python

Comment: Those are on Mac OS X; I wouldn't be surprised if similar things happen on other systems, but the details of how to fix it will need adaptation.